# Horizontally Animate Gradient in HTML5 Canvas using jCanvas & jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, gradient, jcanvas

I want to make the **fill gradient** of a text inside an HTML5 Canvas element to **animate horizontally** to create an *aurora-like effect* by changing the positions of its `colorstops` *(from right to left)* dynamically which, I think, can be done using `setTimeout()` method but I don't know how to do it.

I currently have a static script here:

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/caleb531/jcanvas/master/jcanvas.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var mw = $(document).width();
var mh = $(document).height();

var gs1 = 0
var gs2 = 1/5
var gs3 = 2/5
var gs4 = 3/5
var gs5 = 4/5
var gs6 = 1

$('canvas').attr('width', mw).attr('height', mh);

var Grad = $('canvas').createGradient({
  x1: 0, y1: 0,
  x2: mw, y2: 0,
  c1: '#E33A3A', s1: gs1,
  c2: '#FB57FB', s2: gs2,
  c3: '#21E5EB', s3: gs3,
  c4: '#1ECA18', s4: gs4,
  c5: '#EBD427', s5: gs5,
  c6: '#EB4127', s6: gs6
});

$('canvas').drawText({
  fillStyle: Grad,
  x: mw/2, y: mh/20,
  fontSize: mw/1.8 + '%',
  fromCenter: true,
  fontFamily: "Calibri, Ariel",
  text: 'WOW! Amazing Rainbow!'
})
```

Please help me, and try to use `jCanvas` and `jQuery` syntaxes. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i = setInterval( timer, 500 );
function timer() {
    if(boo!=='change'){
        boo='change';
        a = '#E33A3A';
        b = '#FB57FB';
        c = '#21E5EB';
        d = '#1ECA18';
        e = '#EBD427';
        f = '#EB4127';
    } else {
        boo='other';
        a = '#EB4127';
        b = '#EBD427';
        c = '#1ECA18';
        d = '#21E5EB';
        e = '#FB57FB';
        f = '#E33A3A';
    }
    console.log( boo );
    dragTextAnimatable();
}
```

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9ad1g4eL/)

---

### NATIVE JAVASCRIPT

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4cae9pjv/)

```
var gradient = context.createLinearGradient( 0,0,mw,0);
        for (var i=0; i < colorStops.length; i++) {
            var tempColorStop = colorStops[i];
            var tempColor = tempColorStop.color;
            var tempStopPercent = tempColorStop.stopPercent;
            gradient.addColorStop(tempStopPercent,tempColor);
            tempStopPercent += .015;
            if (tempStopPercent > 1) {
                tempStopPercent = 0;
            }
            tempColorStop.stopPercent = tempStopPercent;;
            colorStops[i] = tempColorStop;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. But is it possible to make a smooth animation effect horizontally like this one: [link](http://www.8bitrocket.com/2012/07/02/html5-canvas-animating-gradients-to-create-a-retro-atari-style-color-cycle/) ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4cae9pjv/